# Apply function to sets of columns in pandas, 'looping' over entire data frame column-wise

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Here is a test example to show what I am trying to achieve. Here's a toy data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,7),index=range(1,11),columns=headers)
```

Which gives

```
    Time       A_x       A_y       A_z       B_x       B_y       B_z
1  -0.075509 -0.123527 -0.547239 -0.453707 -0.969796  0.248761  1.369613
2  -0.206369 -0.112098 -1.122609  0.218538 -0.878985  0.566872 -1.048862
3  -0.194552  0.818276 -1.563931  0.097377  1.641384 -0.766217 -1.482096
4   0.502731  0.766515 -0.650482 -0.087203 -0.089075  0.443969  0.354747
5   1.411380 -2.419204 -0.882383  0.005204 -0.204358 -0.999242 -0.395236
6   1.036695  1.115630  0.081825 -1.038442  0.515798 -0.060016  2.669702
7   0.392943  0.226386  0.039879  0.732611 -0.073447  1.164285  1.034357
8  -1.253264  0.389148  0.158289  0.440282 -1.195860  0.872064  0.906377
9  -0.133580 -0.308314 -0.839347 -0.517989  0.652120  0.477232 -0.391767
10  0.623841  0.473552  0.059428  0.726088 -0.593291 -3.186297 -0.846863
```

What I want to do is simply to calculate the length of the vector for each header (A and B) in this case, for each index, and divide by the `Time` column. Hence, this function needs to be `np.sqrt(A_x^2 + A_y^2 + A_z^2)` and the same for B of course. I.e. I am looking to calculate the velocity for each row, but three columns contribute to one velocity result.

I have tried using `df.groupby` and `df.filter` to loop-over the columns but I cannot really get it to work, because I am not at all sure how I apply effectively the same function to chunks of the data-frame, all in one go (as apparently one is to avoid looping over rows). I have tried doing

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(x.dot(x)), axis=1)
```

This works of course, but only if the input data frame has the right number of columns (3), if longer then the dot-product is calculated over the entire row, and not in chunks of three columns which is what I want (because this is turns corresponds to the tag coordinates, which are three dimensional).

So this is what I am eventually trying to get with the above example (the below arrays are just filled with random numbers, not the actual velocities which I am trying to calculate - just to show what sort of shape I trying to achieve):

```
     Velocity_A  Velocity_B
1    -0.975633   -2.669544
2     0.766405   -0.264904
3     0.425481   -0.429894
4    -0.437316    0.954006
5     1.073352   -1.475964
6    -0.647534    0.937035
7     0.082517    0.438112
8    -0.387111   -1.417930
9    -0.111011    1.068530
10    0.451979   -0.053333
```

My actual data is 50,000 x 36 (so there are 12 tags with x,y,z coordinates), and I want to calculate the velocity all in one go to avoid iterating (if at all possible). There is also a time column of the same length (50,000x1).

How do you do this?

Thanks, Astrid

Answer (score 2):

A possible start.

Filtering out column names corresponding to a particular vector. For example

```
In [20]: filter(lambda x: x.startswith("A_"),df.columns)
Out[20]: ['A_x', 'A_y', 'A_z']
```

Sub selecting these columns from the DataFrame

```
In [22]: df[filter(lambda x: x.startswith("A_"),df.columns)]
Out[22]: 
         A_x       A_y       A_z
1  -0.123527 -0.547239 -0.453707
2  -0.112098 -1.122609  0.218538
3   0.818276 -1.563931  0.097377
4   0.766515 -0.650482 -0.087203
5  -2.419204 -0.882383  0.005204
6   1.115630  0.081825 -1.038442
7   0.226386  0.039879  0.732611
8   0.389148  0.158289  0.440282
9  -0.308314 -0.839347 -0.517989
10  0.473552  0.059428  0.726088
```

So, using this technique you can get chunks of 3 columns. For example.

```
column_initials = ["A","B"]
for column_initial in column_initials:
    df["Velocity_"+column_initial]=df[filter(lambda x: x.startswith(column_initial+"_"),df.columns)].apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(x.dot(x)), axis=1)/df.Time


In [32]: df[['Velocity_A','Velocity_B']]
Out[32]: 
    Velocity_A  Velocity_B
1    -9.555311  -22.467965
2    -5.568487   -7.177625
3    -9.086257  -12.030091
4     2.007230    1.144208
5     1.824531    0.775006
6     1.472305    2.623467
7     1.954044    3.967796
8    -0.485576   -1.384815
9    -7.736036   -6.722931
10    1.392823    5.369757
```

I do not get the same answer as yours. But, I borrowed your `df.apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(x.dot(x)), axis=1)` and assume it is correct.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is more NumPy-ish than Panda-ish, by which I mean the calculation can be expressed somewhat succinctly if you regard your DataFrame as merely a big array, whereas the solution (at least the one I came up with) is more complicated when you try to wrangle the DataFrame with melt, groupby, etc.

The entire calculation can be expressed in essentially one line:

```
np.sqrt((arr**2).reshape(arr.shape[0],-1,3).sum(axis=-1))/times[:,None]
```

So here is the NumPy way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
content = '''
Time       A_x       A_y       A_z       B_x       B_y       B_z
-0.075509 -0.123527 -0.547239 -0.453707 -0.969796  0.248761  1.369613
-0.206369 -0.112098 -1.122609  0.218538 -0.878985  0.566872 -1.048862
-0.194552  0.818276 -1.563931  0.097377  1.641384 -0.766217 -1.482096
 0.502731  0.766515 -0.650482 -0.087203 -0.089075  0.443969  0.354747
 1.411380 -2.419204 -0.882383  0.005204 -0.204358 -0.999242 -0.395236
 1.036695  1.115630  0.081825 -1.038442  0.515798 -0.060016  2.669702
 0.392943  0.226386  0.039879  0.732611 -0.073447  1.164285  1.034357
-1.253264  0.389148  0.158289  0.440282 -1.195860  0.872064  0.906377
-0.133580 -0.308314 -0.839347 -0.517989  0.652120  0.477232 -0.391767
 0.623841  0.473552  0.059428  0.726088 -0.593291 -3.186297 -0.846863'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(content), sep='\s+', header=True)

arr = df.values
times = arr[:,0]
arr = arr[:,1:]
result = np.sqrt((arr**2).reshape(arr.shape[0],-1,3).sum(axis=-1))/times[:,None]
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Velocity_%s'%(x,) for x in list('AB')])
print(result)
```

which yields

```
   Velocity_A  Velocity_B
0   -9.555311  -22.467965
1   -5.568487   -7.177625
2   -9.086257  -12.030091
3    2.007230    1.144208
4    1.824531    0.775006
5    1.472305    2.623467
6    1.954044    3.967796
7   -0.485576   -1.384815
8   -7.736036   -6.722931
9    1.392823    5.369757
```

---

Since your actual DataFrame has shape (50000, 36), choosing a quick method may be important. Here is a benchmark:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

N = 12
col_ids = string.letters[:N]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(50000, 3*N+1), 
    columns=['Time']+['{}_{}'.format(letter, coord) for letter in col_ids
                      for coord in list('xyz')])


def using_numpy(df):
    arr = df.values
    times = arr[:,0]
    arr = arr[:,1:]
    result = np.sqrt((arr**2).reshape(arr.shape[0],-1,3).sum(axis=-1))/times[:,None]
    result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Velocity_%s'%(x,) for x in col_ids])
    return result

def using_loop(df):
    results = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index) # the result container
    for id in col_ids:
        results['Velocity_'+id] = np.sqrt((df.filter(regex=id+'_')**2).sum(axis=1))/df.Time
    return results
```

Using [IPython](http://ipython.org):

```
In [43]: %timeit using_numpy(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.7 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit using_loop(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 82 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do at least a loop over the tag identifier, but don't worry, that's a very fast loop that just determines the filter pattern to get the right columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,7), index=range(1,11), columns='Time A_x A_y A_z B_x B_y B_z'.split())

col_ids = ['A', 'B'] # I guess you can create that one easily

results = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index) # the result container

for id in col_ids:
    results['Velocity_'+id] = np.sqrt((df.filter(regex=id+'_')**2).sum(axis=1))/df.Time
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner...split over many lines for readability:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randn(10,7), 
        index=range(1,11), 
        columns='Time A_x A_y A_z B_x B_y B_z'.split()
        )

result = df\
    .loc[:, df.columns.values!='Time']\
    .T\
    .groupby(lambda x: x[0])\
    .apply(lambda x: np.sqrt((x ** 2).sum()))\
    .T\
    .apply(lambda x: x / df['Time'])

print result

            A          B
1    1.404626   1.310639
2   -2.954644 -10.874091
3    3.479836   6.105961
4    3.885530   2.244544
5    0.995012   1.434228
6   11.278208  11.454466
7   -1.209242  -1.281165
8   -5.175911  -5.905070
9   11.889318  16.758958
10  -0.978014  -0.590767
```

Note: I am a bit frustrated that I needed to thrown in the two transposes.  I just couldn't get `groupby` and `apply` to play nicely with `axis=1`.  If someone could show me how to do that, I'd be very grateful.  The trick here was knowing that when you call `groupby(lambda x: f(x))` that `x` is the value of the index for each row.  So `groupby(lambda x: x[0])` groups by the first letter of the row index.  After doing the transposition, this was `A` or `B`.

---

Ok, no more transposes:

```
result = df\
    .loc[:, df.columns!='Time']\
    .groupby(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)\
    .apply(lambda x: np.sqrt((x**2).sum(1)))\
    .apply(lambda x: x / df['Time'])

print result

            A          B
1    1.404626   1.310639
2   -2.954644 -10.874091
3    3.479836   6.105961
4    3.885530   2.244544
5    0.995012   1.434228
6   11.278208  11.454466
7   -1.209242  -1.281165
8   -5.175911  -5.905070
9   11.889318  16.758958
10  -0.978014  -0.590767
```