# Process an entire column from a DataFrameGroupby

Tags: pandas, apply, reduce

I have a function which processes two Series. The algorithm requires the function to receive the whole Series.
I have data stored in a DataFrameGroupBy object. Therefore, I would like to apply the function to the entire column. 
Which is the most idiomatic way to proceed?

I have produced some code trying to simplify the problem at hand:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'clients': pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']),
    'odd1': pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']),
    'odd2': pd.Series(['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])})

def strange_fun(s1, s2):
    return np.sum(s1) + np.sum(s2)

df.groupby('clients')[['odd1', 'odd2']].apply(lambda el: strange_fun(el[0], el[1]), axis=0)
```

I am a little [bit confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875140/apply-function-to-sets-of-columns-in-pandas-looping-over-entire-data-frame-co)

Comment: Is your data supposed to be strings? Are they in fact numeric?

Comment: It does not matter. It's just for the sake of having an example.

Comment: The normal idiomatic method is to `df.groupby('col_name')[col].agg(func)` so in your case `df.groupby('clients')[['odd1', 'odd2']].agg(np.sum)` but I don't know if this produces the output you desire

Comment: Also, the `apply` method of a GroupBy object doesnt have the `axis` keyword, die `apply` method of a DataFrame does.

Comment: @EdChum: nope. This does not produce the desired output. The function I have works on two columns. What you did just applies a function which works on one column to `[['odd1', 'odd2']]`

Comment: @RuthgerKassies: I think I read in the linked stackoverflow question that `axis` has been added to the `apply` method of the `GroupBy` object. But this is obviously not the case, given the error message I get back from the Python console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is passing the entire group (as a DataFrame) an option, and then split it inside the function?

If you need to reference the actual columns, passing the names can be done:

```
def strange_fun(el, cols):

    s1 = el[cols[0]]
    s2 = el[cols[1]]

    return np.sum(s1) + np.sum(s2)

df.groupby('clients')[['odd1', 'odd2']].apply(lambda el: strange_fun(el, ['odd1', 'odd2']))
```

Or simply by integer-indexing the columns:

```
def strange_fun(el):

    s1 = el.iloc[:,0]
    s2 = el.iloc[:,1]

    return np.sum(s1) + np.sum(s2)

df.groupby('clients')[['odd1', 'odd2']].apply(lambda el: strange_fun(el))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great stuff. Passing the entire group is the workaround I just came up with but when I will use the whole dataset I will have to handle quite a large amount of data. In any case, however, the dataframe should be passed by reference, isn't it?